# Extra space before notes in threeparttable

Tags: tables, overleaf, threeparttable

I'm using threeparttable to add notes to a table, but it's compiling with an extra space between the notes and bottom of the table. I'd like the notes to be flush with the table but can't seem to figure out why it's behaving this way. [image: This is what the minimal working example looks like compiled]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\emergencystretch=1em
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[nohead]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\geometry{left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \centering
    \caption{Title of table}
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
        \toprule
         & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Class 1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Class 2} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7} 
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)} 
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)} 
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)} \\
        \midrule
        Outcome      &      0.055         &      0.053        &     -0.010          &      0.064         &      0.034         &      0.023         \\
                       &    (0.066)         &    (0.072)         &    (0.066)                &    (0.052)         &    (0.052)         &    (0.068)         \\
        \bottomrule
        \label{tab:main_est}
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \small
         \item Notes: Notes are too far from table. Significance levels are indicated as 0.05\sym{*}  0.01\sym{**}  0.001\sym{***}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! To get rid of the extra vertical white space, move the `\label` directly after the `\caption`.

Comment: I didn't see this comment before. You (@leandriis) can replace my answer with your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tabular environment has one extra text row after the `\bottomrule`, containing only the invisible `\label` anchor point. You should move the `\label` elsewhere.

After that, if you find the notes are then too close, you could change the final `\bottomrule` to `\midrule`.